# How to reiterate same loop again in php?

Tags: php

I have the following foreach loop, how can I reiterate over the same loop index again?

```
$n = 0;
$currentTotal = 0;
$currentSettlement = $coupons[0]->settlement_id;
foreach ($coupons as $coupon){
    if($currentSettlement == $coupon->settlement_id){
        $currentTotal += $coupon->amount;
    }else{
        $settlements[$n]['total'] = $currentTotal;
        $currentTotal = 0;
        $currentSettlement = $coupon->settlement_id;
        $n++;
        // after this I want to reiterate current loop from the beginning
    }

}
```

Comment: by that you mean reset the foreach? idon't think you can with foreach, maybe using while you can actually reset it

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing this? I can't think of any.

Comment: you can call a function from else part.

Comment: Instead of a foreach loop, you could use a generator function.  Otherwise, you might need to wrap that foreach with a function and then make repeated function calls.

Comment: I am thinking of using a for loop instead foreach, as foreach can't go to previous iteration

Answer (score 0):

If you want necessary foreach loop you can use a function which you fix that it runs only twice:

```
$n = 0;
$currentTotal = 0;
$currentSettlement = $coupons[0]->settlement_id;
for2loop(1,$coupons);

function for2loop($loopagain,$coupons)
{

    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        if ($currentSettlement == $coupon->settlement_id) {
            $currentTotal += $coupon->amount;
        } else {
            $settlements[$n]['total'] = $currentTotal;
            $currentTotal = 0;
            $currentSettlement = $coupon->settlement_id;
            $n++;
            if($loopagain == 1)
                for2loop(2,$coupons); // after this I want to reiterate current loop from the beginning
        }

    }
    return $currentSettlement
}
```

but i think that yu must prefer while loop or for loop better